# Swashbuckle swagger.json larger than 4 mb net core

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

My api endpoint have grown too large and I need to minimize it or divide it to multiple swagger.json files.
I want to upload the swagger.json file to power automate but there are two rules. Max 4 Mb and Max 256 functions per file. I don´t meet these requirement.

**I want to have a swagger file per controller/group this will minimize number of functions and decrease the size of file.
But I don't know how to configure(Swashbuckle) or should I do it with documentFilters?**

I already use ApiVersioning to decrease a littel bit of functions and size, but it is not enough. And I can´t chnage the complete url endpoint. I just want multiple files more than just versions.

Comment: I think you can use "groups" but I forget the specifics. Perhaps try using that as one of your search terms

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks i use the groupname. And if I change this setting the url is changing. i.e localhost/api/v1/orders and it is changed to localhost/api/v1.orders/orders. So the group is the right way and I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to make this possible. But I want to make it without changing any urls to the existing api.

1. In each controller you can add set the Apiversion  `[ApiVersion("2.0")]` and then set the controllername i.e `[ApiVersion("2.0.order")]`. And there will be a version for each controller.
   **This solution will change the urls and are not approachable for an existing api.**
2. Another solution is to create tags for each operation with a filter and now we can create a filter for each endpoint

```
    public class ApplySwaggerOperationTags : IOperationFilter
        {
            public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
            {
                var tag = new OpenApiTag();
                context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues.TryGetValue("controller",out string tagname);
                tag.Name = tagname;
                operation.Tags.Add(tag);
    
                var tagGroupName = new OpenApiTag();
                tagGroupName.Name = context.ApiDescription.GroupName;
                operation.Tags.Add(tagGroupName);
            }
        }
```

And then apply a document filter

```
 public class SwaggerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            // Key is read-only so make a copy of the Paths property
            var pathsFiltered = new OpenApiPaths();
            var array = context.DocumentName.Split("-");
            string version = array[0];
            string tag = string.Empty;
            if (array.Count() > 1)
            {
                tag = array[1];
            }

            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
            {
                if (path.Value.Operations.Values.First().Tags.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == version) != null)
                {
                    if (path.Value.Operations.Values.First().Tags.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.ToLower() == tag.ToLower()) != null ||
                        tag == string.Empty)
                    {
                        // Add the path to the filtered collection
                        pathsFiltered.Add(path.Key, path.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            swaggerDoc.Paths = pathsFiltered;
        }
    }
```

**The key is to have  c.SwaggerEndpoint(in UseSwaggerUI) and options.SwaggerDoc(in SwaggerGenOptions) that match**

And a good example to check is https://github.com/cbruen1/SwaggerFilter.
Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Just from reading the code: Doing a `FirstOrDefault().Whatever` can lead to NullReferenceExceptions. Either make a `First().Whatever` or (I think in your case better maches) a `FirstOrDefault()?.Whatever`.

Comment: @Oliver  Yes correct First() is better. Then you get a an better exception. But hopefully this will not occour becuse the tags are automaticlly added.